# Can not access my external hard drive.

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting, filenames

I am fairly new to Linux and have been trying to move some files around with terminal on my external hard drive but I can't seem to get it to work. I am using a generic external hard drive with a ext4 format but not matter what I try I can't do anything with it through my terminal. The Drive's name does have spaces in it so when ever I do something in terminal it tries to separate the externals name and the spits out no directory found. is there a way to make it recognize the name without removing the spaces? Any help would be more than grateful.

Comment: You can either quote the name of the drive: `/media/'name of my drive'` or use backslashes to escape the spaces: `/media/name\ of\ my\ drive`

Comment: ... or don't put spaces in names.

Comment: lol well i had named the drive before i started using linux and i have been using that drive for years so i would hate to change its name now just because of this. but thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Linux!  A trick that will get you started here (and will save you from getting carpal tunnel in the future) is "tab completion":

```
$ ls /med
```

then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see

```
$ ls /media/
```

If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, you might see a list of possible options to continue the path,

```
$ ls /media/
MyBigExternalDrive/    My Example Hard Drive/
```

or (if there is only one path) the entire path will be completed:

```
$ ls /media/My\ Example\ Hard\ Drive/
```

Tricks like this are nice because you can learn seemingly unrelated syntax.  In this case, you can write out paths with spaces by putting a `\` in front of the space.

Comment: Oh wow. thank you so much i never knew about this miricle called tab complete. that should shorten how much i have to type quite alot.